# D3.js function to randomly call a tooltip in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have created a d3.js map for a presentation using reveal.js and wanted to write a function that would randomly call the tooltip for one of the cities displayed in the map to have an animated title slide basically. However, I have no idea about how to start. Is there a certain way I should create a tooltip to use for the popup?

The map uses the following to show the tooltip:

```
.on("mouseover", showTooltip)
.on("mouseout", removeTooltip);

function showTooltip(d) {
    $(this).popover({
        placement: 'auto top',
        container: '#map',
        trigger: 'manual',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return "<span style='font-size: 11px; text-align: center;'>" + d.City + "</span>";
        }
    });
    $(this).popover('show');

    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
}

function removeTooltip() {
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", opacityCircles);

    $('.popover').each(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

}
```

I already have built a function that animates the cities by making them randomly grow and shrink.

```
function grow() {
    d3.select(this)
    .transition("growing").duration(1000 + 4000 * Math.random())
    .delay(function (d, i) {
        return Math.random() * 1000;
    })
    .attr("r", 8)
    .style("opacity", function (d) {
        return Math.min(1,
            0.2 + Math.random() * 2);
    })
    .transition("shrinking").duration(1000 + 3000 * Math.random())
    .attr("r", 2)
    .style("opacity", function (d) {
        return Math.min(1,
            0.2 + Math.random() * 2);
    })
    .each("end", grow);

}
```

How can I combine these two to create a function that makes the circle representing a city grow and display its tooltip, then shrink and have the tooltip disappear?

Comment: what if you call grow() directly after $(this).popover('show'); in your showTooltip function?

Comment: I would like it to be part of the grow function cuz its set into a loop. Imagine a map with various circles randomly highlighted and a tooltip showing the city's name

Comment: I found code that does what i'd like but I don't know how to adapt it to my case. `(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var tt = $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');

    setInterval(function () {

        // hide all tooltips
        tt.tooltip('hide');
        // show the one we want (use toggle - as show will compete with hide)
        $(tt[i++ % tt.length]).tooltip('toggle');

    }, 2000);
})();`